# shorten the graphql field value

Tags: graphql

I am trying to fetch image path in an alias field using graphql, I am able to get output like this:

#### Output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "leaders": [
      {
        "partyImg": {
          "image": {
            "url": "/uploads/17a5f020cc974679ac52e56a22b74dd6.png"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "partyImg": {
          "image": {
            "url": "/uploads/70bd673d41654058847e39c14cda5fef.png"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "partyImg": {
          "image": {
            "url": "/uploads/c54a0ace0bb34da3985c67945b1d0bf0.png"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I used the following graphql code:

#### Input:

```
query Leaders{
  leaders{
    partyImg: party{image: Image{ url }},
  }
}
```

The output I am trying to get is:

#### Expected output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "leaders": [
      {
        "partyImg": "/uploads/17a5f020cc974679ac52e56a22b74dd6.png"
      },
      {
        "partyImg": "/uploads/70bd673d41654058847e39c14cda5fef.png"
      },
      {
        "partyImg": "/uploads/c54a0ace0bb34da3985c67945b1d0bf0.png"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please help me to prepare the graphql input which could generate the expected output.

Comment: It looks like the schema you are querying doesn't return the data in that format. If you want the data in the format you mention, the schema needs to change or else you have to post-process the data yourself to get the desired shape. It looks like the schema (according to input) has a list of leaders with a party object that contains an Image object with a url property. This structure is fixed and alias only lets you rename fields with the same shape, so your query is simply renaming the party object to partyImg and Image to image.

Comment: oh I thought we could change the value as well.. my bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the graphql schema prevents you from getting the data in the format that you want. Based on your input query, I expect the schema looks something like this:

```
query {
    leaders: [Leader]
}
type Leader {
    party: Party
}
type Party {
    Image: Image
}
type Image {
    url: String
}
```

To get the data in the format that you want, you would need a schema that looks more like:

```
query {
    leaders: [Leader]
}
type Leader {
    party: Party,
    imageUrl: String
}
```

Then you could do:

```
query Leaders {
    leaders {
        partyImg: imageUrl
    }
}
```

I assume you don't control the schema, so you would have to do post processing. If you are using javascript, the following could work for the above output as a simple mapping exercise.

```js
(function() {
  var output = {
    "data": {
      "leaders": [{
          "partyImg": {
            "image": {
              "url": "/uploads/17a5f020cc974679ac52e56a22b74dd6.png"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "partyImg": {
            "image": {
              "url": "/uploads/70bd673d41654058847e39c14cda5fef.png"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "partyImg": {
            "image": {
              "url": "/uploads/c54a0ace0bb34da3985c67945b1d0bf0.png"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  var transformed = {
    data: {
      leaders: output.data.leaders.map(function flattenUrl(item) {
        return {
          partyImg: item.partyImg.image.url
        };
      })
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('transformedOutput').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(transformed);
}());
```

```html
<div id="transformedOutput"></div>
```

If you are the author of this graphql schema, you can structure it in whatever way makes the most sense to your applications and/or consumers.